# getting error for rmagick and magick-config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am using rvm 1.9.3 and rails 3.
But while running bundle install for my app, I'm getting this error.

> current directory:
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20180628-13119-1ds4iy4.rb extconf.rb checking for Ruby
>   version >= 1.8.5... yes checking for gcc... yes checking for
>   Magick-config... no Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find
>   Magick-config in
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
```

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/mkmf.log

> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out

Note: I already used the commands
sudo apt-get install build-essential imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Comment: So what does it say in the `mkmf.log` and `gem_make.out` files that it tells you to look in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue some time ago, I install the ImageMagick and other stuff still I was getting an error installing rmagick

the only thing works for me is running this with sudo, might work for you too

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
```

from here 
https://github.com/rmagick-temp/rmagick/issues/133#issuecomment-185414504

Comment: removing ImageMagick fully from the system and reinstalling might work